# What's the difference between id<MTLDevice> and MTLDevice*?

Tags: objective-c, metal

When accessing a MTLDevice, the tutorial always encourages `id<MTLDevice>` rather than `MTLDevice*`.

If id is used as a pointer pointing to any ObjC object, then what's the difference between `id<MTLDevice>` and `MTLDevice*`?

Why MTLDevice is not correct? It shows "**Type argument 'GDevice *' (aka 'struct GDevice *') is neither an Objective-C object nor a block type**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `id<P>` means “an object that conforms to protocol `P`”.

In contrast, `T*` means “a pointer to an object of type/class `T`”.

But [`MTLDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice?language=objc) is a protocol and not a type/class. This is why we use `id<MTLDevice>`, not `MTLDevice *`.

So, consider the following:

```
id<MTLDevice> device;
```

That means that `device` is a reference to an object that conforms to the `MTLDevice` protocol.

For more information for about the use of `id` with these angular brackets, see [Programming with Objective-C: Working with Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW2).

Comment: Thanks. For object type, is there a difference between id<type> and type*?

Comment: `id<P>` means “an object that conforms to protocol `P`”, whereas `T*` is “an object that is of type `T`”. In [Programming with Objective-C: Working with Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW2) it says “Objective-C uses angle brackets to indicate conformance to a protocol.”  So, it’s not `id<type>`, but rather `id<protocol>`. And because `MTLDevice` is a protocol and not a type, that’s why we use `id<MTLDevice>`.